# Upload S3 object to a versioned bucket with a custom Version ID via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload an object to an S3 bucket with a custom version ID using the AWS CLI. This function is supported by the CLI?
Now, when I upload an object the Version ID is created by default. Which options should I use to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't supply custom version IDs. See the [Object Versioning documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectVersioning.html).

> If you have enabled versioning, Amazon S3 assigns a unique version ID value for the object.

and:

> Only Amazon S3 generates version IDs. They cannot be edited.